# pandas - comparing two columns of different dataframes with multiple strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm pretty new to pandas and got an assignment asking me to compare & match two columns of 2 different .csv files. 
dtypes are strings

1st df
Name     | Subjects 
Student1 | Biology, Math, German
Student2 | Sport, Biology, English
Student3 | Chemistry, Math, Biology

2nd df
Name     | Subjects
Teacher1 | Biology, Sport, English
Teacher2 | Chemistry, Math, Physics
Teacher3 | Biology, Physics, Chemistry, English
...

Now, I should compare and find the best match between a Student & Teacher. 
Meaning, they should match at least 1 subject, but for a "perfect match" all of them.

I tried different things already - pd.merge, iterrows, isin, etc. - but can't find a great performant solution.

I'm not asking for a solution for my assignment, but for a small push in the right direction.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! A couple of questions: What do you mean by "best match"? Must there be an exact match? Does the order of subjects matter? Answering questions like this would help us help you better.

Comment: No, the order does not matter. Best case would be indeed an exact match, but it does not have to be.

Comment: So does "best match" mean that they must match in at least one subject? If so, great if you can edit the question by clicking the "edit" button near the bottom of your question.

Comment: Thanks, @georgbhm. I hope my answer helps you! Let me know if there are any problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you said you didn't want a solution, but a push in the right direction, here is how I would approach the problem:

1. Read both datasets as lists. Let's call the dataframes student and teacher.

e.g.

```
students = """Name | Subjects
Student1 | Biology, Math, German
Student2 | Sport, Biology, English
Student3 | Chemistry, Math, Biology""".replace(" |", ",").splitlines()[1:]

students = [student.split(',') for student in students]
```

The first line replaces the vertical separators '|' with ','. It then splits the line and omits the first line (header).

The next Python command then ensures that each student appears as a list, to facilitate easy conversion to Pandas DataFrames.

students is now `[['Name', ' Subjects'], ['Student1', ' Biology', ' Math', ' German'], ['Student2', ' Sport', ' Biology', ' English'], ['Student3', ' Chemistry', ' Math', ' Biology']]`

2. Convert both `student` and `teacher` into pandas dataframes. The first column in the dataframe will be the student/teacher identifier, and there will be one column for each subject. Some cells will be left blank e.g. if some students take as many as four subjects and others take two, then the students who take two subjects will have two empty cells in their rows. My initial guess to executing this approach would be to use two separators: '|' and ','. Or you can convert '|' into ',' by using the `.replace()` method and just use one separator.

   `students = pd.DataFrame(students, columns=['name', 's1', 's2', 's3'])`

students then becomes

```
       name          s1        s2        s3
0  Student1     Biology      Math    German
1  Student2       Sport   Biology   English
2  Student3   Chemistry      Math   Biology
```

3. Then use the pandas `wide_to_long` method to change both datasets into "long" formats. In other words, each student/teacher will have one row per subject they take. So if a student takes 3 subjects, they will have 3 rows.

`df = pd.wide_to_long(students, ["s"], i="name", j="subject").reset_index()`

`students` now becomes

```
       name  subject           s
0  Student1        1     Biology
1  Student2        1       Sport
2  Student3        1   Chemistry
3  Student1        2        Math
4  Student2        2     Biology
5  Student3        2        Math
6  Student1        3      German
7  Student2        3     English
8  Student3        3     Biology
```

4. Merge the student and teacher dataframe on subject, then use groupby to group by (student, teacher) combination to find for each student, which teacher is a "best match".

I'll leave the last step to you, but will continue to monitor this thread to see if you have any problems (you can comment to send me a notification).

Feel free to upvote/accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: Thank you! For some reason I always get an empty dataframe after pd.wide... before doing that the frame seems fine (tested by printing it) - any idea what could cause that?

Comment: btw. all datatypes are objects

Answer (score 0):

You can first pivot on subject column using `pd.pivot_table` and then do a `ofpd.merge` on `subject` columns of `student` and `teacher` tables to relate teachers and students based on subjects.